# STM32F4 USART1 sends garbage

Tags: stm32, cortex-m, cmsis

I am having a problem when Sending char from STM32F411 to PC it reads into garbage, but when I do the opposite operation the MCU correctly reads char sent.

I perform following actions:

1. Enable GPIOA clock and configure pins 9 and 10 alternate function.
2. Enable USART1, leave default values for M (message length), stop bits, DMA
3. Set `USARTDIV` to result in 9600 baud at 16Mhz (HSI) *
4. Configure USART to send idle frame as first transmission

* I have also tried with 100Mhz `APB2` bus frequency with the same result.

**Configuring USART**

```
// 1. Enable USART
SET_BIT(USART1->CR1, USART_CR1_UE);
// 5. Select the desired baud rate in BRR
SET_BIT(USART1->BRR, 0x683);        // USARTDIV
// 6. Set TE in CR1 to send an idle frame as first transmission
SET_BIT(USART1->CR1, USART_CR1_TE);
```

After that I am trying to accept an `a` character with *RealTerm2.0* with following configuration: `9600 8N1 None`

Character is sent by following code:

```
void SendChar_USART(char pChar)
{
    // Transmitter 7, 8
    // 7. Write the data to send in the DR register (this clears TXE)
    USART1->DR = pChar;
    while(!READ_BIT(USART1->SR, USART_SR_TXE));
}
```

---

**Update 1**

Switching to USART2 with absolute same configuration solves the problem and it is possible to recover text from serial terminal, however this question unanswered "Why USART1 does not work as expected?"

Comment: what are each connected to, perhaps usart1 is tied to an on chip usb to serial or a debug header/mcu.

Comment: @old_timer I have a a discovery board and according to the schematics in the datasheet they are connected to EMIF02 (EMI filter) supply pin and ID pins. It seems that there are no elements that may influence signals on high frequencies.

That is probably the cause of the problem, but still interesting why only outbound channel is disrupted. It's my mistake that didn't check that in the first place. Should I delete my question now?

Comment: I dont think you have to if you dont want can leave it in this state or you can answer your own question, I know there is a way to do that or a time to do that which is not offensive (search around for the answer to that).  Looking at my code I guess I only used uart2 and didnt mess with uart1, I know one of these boards I echoed what came in one uart out the other and put a loopback on the one not connected to the stlink.

Comment: If you have not actually gotten it to work and if the pins are free to the edge then it should then figure that out.  since you have uart2 working you can use that to figure out uart1, put a loopback on it rather than whatever you were connecting it to, send something out and check the receiver to see if it came back, repeat with other data.

Comment: what did you hook up to uart1 to see if it was working?

Comment: Yeah, a super quick look at the schematic nothing jumps out yet.  You should be able to hook that up to a 3.3v usb to uart board/cable and see what is going on there, or a scope or loop it back on itself.

Comment: @old_timer I am using **CP210x USB to UART bridge**. While sending data from UART1 I receive usually 2 times more characters then I've sent and they mostly have values greater than 170. For UART loopback check I assume I need to write a simple code receiving and sending back data from RX to TX.

Answer (score 1):

There is a capacitor on the way to the PA9 pin of the extension connector filtering out the USART1 TX. Peter Harrison explains the issue very well, i think.

http://www.micromouseonline.com/2013/05/05/using-usart1-on-the-stm32f4discovery/